# Using first_or_create in Sidekiq Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq Job with first_or_create.

```
 class JobWithFirstOrCreate
    analysis = Analysis.where(standard_id: standard_id).first_or_create
    analysis.save!
 end
```

But this causes uniqueness validation to fail due to duplicate analysis records being created. I understand this is because first_or_create is not atomic.

So what is the right way of doing this?
I want to run jobs concurrently in which I update if an analysis record is already present else insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the term "upsert".  ActiveRecord can't do it natively but you can roll the SQL by hand.

Comment: I use Postgres and the following query seems to work fine.    "INSERT into analysis ( standard_id, top_score ) values( #{standard_id}, #{top_score} ) on conflict ( standard_id ) do update set ( top_score ) = ( #{top_score} )"

Comment: Yep, that'll work great.  Mysql can do something similar.